# Why does running top inside docker container only show processes inside the container?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm running top inside a docker container and I'm seeing that the only processes that show up are the initial process used to run the container and top. Why does it show this instead of displaying other processes on the docker host as well?

Comment: The container is pretending to be a little computer. It's the same reason you can bring up a task manager on a virtual machine running in the cloud without seeing the 725 billion other processes being run on that particular hypervisor.

Comment: Similar example phrased another way: if you're SSH'ed onto another server and run top, you'll only see the processes on that server not your computer as well.

Comment: Definitely *not* the same as the two comments above described. :) Docker is *not* a virtual machine. It does not emulate a physical computer in the same way as a virtual machine does, but rather runs under the same OS. As for the comparison with SSH... well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to understand why this is happening, you need to understand the basic concepts of Linux that Docker is taking advantage of.

There is this feature in the Linux Kernel called `namespaces` that partitions/isolates the host resources in way where a set of processes sees one set of resources where as another set of processes sees another set of resources.

Linux has 7 types of namespaces:

- Mount - isolate mount points
- UTS - isolate hostname
- IPC - isolate interprocess communication resources
- PID - isolate the PID number space
- Network - isolate network interfaces
- User - isolate UID/GID number spaces
- Cgroup - isolate cgroup root directory

When you are working on your linux machine everything that you do is on the same namespace, but when you create a container by doing `docker run` by default it'll create a new separate namespace to isolate the container from your host.

In the specific case of your question, you see just one process running because the container is in a different PID namespace as your host machine.

You can tell Docker to share the same PID namespace by using `--pid="host"` when you create the container, there are some cases when doing that is useful.